# PHP and static class methods

Tags: php, class, static, static-methods

I am looking for a better understanding of how static methods work in php. I have been reading the article on the php manual site about [static keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) in releation to methods, and class objects and I am curious about something.

Lets say I have this class:

```
class Something{
    protected static $_something = null;

    public function __construct($options = null){
        if(self::$_something === null && $options != null){ 
            self::$_something = $options 
        }
    }

    public function get_something(){ return self::$_something }
}
```

So you instantiate this on `index.php`, so you do something like:

```
$class_instantiation = new Something(array('test' => 'example'));
```

Great, at this point `$_something` contains an array of `key=>value`, on this same page we can do:

```
var_dump($class_instantiation->get_something()); // var dumps the array we passed in.
```

**BUT**

If we now create `sample.php` and do:

```
$class_instantiation = new Something();
var_dump($class_instantiation->get_something());
```

We get `null` back (I assume you went to `index.php`, instantiated the class and passed in the array, saw the `var_dump` **THEN** navigated to `sample.php`. It is understandable how this would return `null` if you only went to `sample.php` without first going to `index.php`.)

I assumed that static methods are *"saved across all instances of the class"*, thus I should be able to instantiate the class with or with out an object passed into the constructor, assume that something is there and get back my array we created on `index.php`

So my question is:

**How does static methods really work in terms of classes? Is there a way to do what I am trying to do with out the use of third party tools if I am just passing objects around?**

Comment: A Static property means that there is only ever one `instance` of that property no matter who few or how many instances of the class you create; and static !== persistent

Comment: Also as a side-note, it's better to use `static::` instead of `self::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static property is `static` across the same PHP execution.  If you run it on `index.php`, then at the end of execution it is destroyed.  On `sample.php` it will be a new execution.  This works as you expect (same execution):

```
//index.php
class Something{
    protected static $_something = null;

    public function __construct($options = null){
        if(self::$_something === null && $options != null){ 
            self::$_something = $options ;
        }
    }

    public function get_something(){ return self::$_something; }
}

$class_instantiation = new Something(array('test' => 'example'));
var_dump($class_instantiation->get_something());

$class_instantiation2 = new Something();
var_dump($class_instantiation2->get_something());
```

Both `objects` dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(7) "example"
}
```

Comment: so this cannot be used across multiple "pages" so `sample.php` could not call `$class_instantiation = new Something(array('test' => 'example'));` and get the same array as `index.php`?

Comment: Yes, if you pass the same array it will give the same result, but that's not what you were doing.  The `static` property would be destroyed so you would HAVE to pass in the array again.

Answer (score 1):

`static` in PHP also means that you could access to property/method without instatiating the class. It's hard to keep `static` variables across the same PHP execution as, often, your execution will end with a server response but as [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver) says, they act as you expect within the same execution (same request, read that way)